# Reset Active Operator

Tags: python, operator

I want to write a `Handler` that runs code only when the user **stops** translating an object, using `bpy.ops.transform.translate` (the 'G' key). So while the user is sliding the mouse around, nothing should happen besides the object being translated. But when they **exit** the modal `operator` (by left-clicking or pressing 'enter'), my code should run.

My approach:

```
@bpy.app.handlers.persistent
def detect_change(scene):
    op = bpy.context.active_operator
    opname = op.bl_idname.replace("_OT_", ".").lower() if op else ''

    # On entering translate mode, start checking for exit
    if opname == "transform.translate":
        waiting = True # This will be some sort of persistent variable.
        return

    # If not in translate mode, then run code
    elif waiting:
        my_function()
        waiting = False

# Add the handler
bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.append(detect_change)
```

The only problem is that after exiting the translate modal operator, the active_operator remains at `transform.translate`. It doesn't switch until another operator is called.

Any way to either force the operator to update to `None` or to detect exiting the modal operator?

Comment: You may wanna look into Macros, but there is no real reliable way to achieve this. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/alternate-between-user-input-and-automation-in-one-step-script

Comment: So the idea would be to call the macro instead of directly invoking `transform.translate`? A bit inconvenient for the user to have to remember, but I see how that could work.

Comment: Keep in mind that in macro calling a modal op and then a regular op, the regular op will be executed **before** the modal op. Waiting for a modal op to finished is not officially supported. But you may be able to circumvent it with another modal op, that needs to be invoked and wait for the event that ends the other modal op (yes, this is really hacky not and never fully reliable).

Comment: Oh weird. In that case, I'll hold out. I wonder if there's room for `post_operator` and `pre_operator` `Handlers`? (I know they don't exist, just wondering if it would be useful addition).

Comment: [window_manager.operators](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.WindowManager.html?highlight=window_manager#bpy.types.WindowManager.operators) keeps a log of the recent operators. Not sure if it is useful and what it does.

Comment: Not sure exactly what it does, but what I need is actually an indicator that the operator has *finished*

Comment: @supergra If you've figured out an answer you should post it, I need a similar solution.

Comment: No, I gave up. Never figured it out.